# send command via tcp ip through javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I want to achieve following functionality and need the help for the same:

1. I have one server on which there is device connected that prints some bar codes based on pre-formatted command given to it.
2. Currently there is one desktop application which generates the command and does the job.
3. Now I want to do this via web, meaning there will be one webpage (say .aspx) and I want to achieve this by javascript.

I am able to generate the pre-formatted command required for printing but I don't know how to send the command to server, whether socket tcp ip or something else.

I have tried using node.js, socket.io, json-socket etc. but nothing is working,

Comment: If you are using TCP why not a web socket?

Comment: web socket depends on ws protocol which i dont want

Comment: Ok, sorry... only thing I could think of ;)

Answer (score 1):

If javascript is a fixed requirement, then no I don't think you'll find a *direct* solution. You will need to create an intermediary service that will translate websocket protocol to the tcp/ip protocol your software communicates on. I found a package called [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) that has implementations of this kind of bridge in a few different languages.

Although if you are open to using Flash on the front end, and can meet the security requirements on your backend connection, then [Flash socket API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) could work. I believe Java applets can also manage this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible to do from inside a web browser. If it were it would be a huge security vulnerability (think about it, you visit an attackers page and all of a sudden your printer starts printing and every shared directory on your network fills to the brim with junk data).

You could run the command on the server (node/.net/anything else...) and have the web platform talk to the server to kick the process off. But that sounds kind of like what you already have set up...

Alternately, if you can change the software on the connected device you could try to give it an HTTP endpoint which responds to POSTs.

Comment: Is there any way to include or work with socket in javascript ?

Comment: @pratik not at a low level I do not think so.